# Android Edit box focus

Tags: android, focus, editbox

NewBie Androider here.

I am writing a code in which user enters only one ALPHABET in one edit box then focus moves to other one. If it is not Alphabet then cursor will remain at edit box 1 
 If user delete the character then cursor remain at the same edit box.

Also if user click on editbox having some character in it then it should get removed when clicked.

Below is my attempt

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
          final EditText et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.box1);
          final  EditText et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.box2);

        et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){
            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,
            int start, int count, int after){

            }
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,
            int start, int before, int count)
            {
                if(isAlphabet(et1.getText().toString())){
                    et2.requestFocus();
                }else{
                    et1.setText("");
                    et1.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Also I have four edit box and I want to focus on the next empty box... any suggestion to implement this logic.

Thanks

Comment: And, what is the problem with the code you have shown?

Comment: Problem is when I enter some Number its stop working.
though my 
android:inputType="text|textCapCharacters|textNoSuggestions"
still I can enter any number
 also if user click on editbox having some character in it then it should get removed when clicked and focus will be on same edit box.

Comment: Can you show the `isAlphabet` method?

Comment: public static boolean isAlphabet(String str)
    {
       return str.matches("[a-zA-Z]");
     }

THough this problem get solved by @hossam solution

android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz." with this I can only enter alphabets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in each edittext in layout.XML just use

> android:inputtype="text"

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz."
```

Comment: android:inputType="text|textCapCharacters|textNoSuggestions" still I can enter any digits

Comment: try this one ;) I tested it  


android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz."

android:inputType="text"

Comment: instead of using initial text use

android:Hint="Enter text here"

when you click on the editText it becomes empty ;)

Comment: Yes, I have added android:Hint in the layout and used OnFocusChangeListener to resetting the editbox. It is working fine.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firstly since you want your user only to input characters not number then give `android:inputtype="text"` so that the edittext can only take text not numbers and then give `android:maxLength="1"` so that only one character can be inputted.

when on-click of an ediitext to remove/flush the contents in an edittext you have to implement the `onCLick()` method of your edittext and do : `edittext.setText("")`. You also should focus the edittext which you want the focus to be at by the .requestFocus()

Comment: android:inputType="text|textCapCharacters|textNoSuggestions"
still I can enter any digits

Comment: also
  et1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    et1.setText("");
    et1.requestFocus();
    
   }
  });
not working... crashing the app

Comment: Now OnClickListener is working... but I have to click two time to reset the value.

here is the code
    et1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
          et1.setText("");
    
   }
  }
        );